# Content of static cells not appearing UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I have a `UITableViewController` that has a table view with static cells. I have added some costume cells with `UIImageView` and `UILabel` in them. Everything looks fine in the xcode storyboard: [image]

since the cells are static I do NOT implement the datasource methods here's my code for the table view controler:

```
    #import "MainTableViewController.h"

    @interface MainTableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation MainTableViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @end
```

but when I run the code in the simulator the cells' content won't appeare:
[image]

here's the Scene hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your auto layout constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have problem with constraints! If you have wrong constraint for elements inside cell, elements will not shown!

Comment: @Arayn kheyli khobi:D

Answer (score 19):

UITableView with static cells not showing up for me either - I tried to remove and re-add the segue. Everything was properly set up. The trick....

The trick is to remove the following row, cell, and section methods from your UITableViewController subclass. They are automatically added by Xcode, but if you are using static cells, you don’t want them in your class.

```
– (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

– (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

– (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Once you have removed these methods, your cells will show up correctly.

Comment: so glad i found your answer before pouring my precious time into searching more

Comment: give this guy a medal!

Comment: Sorry, I can give you 1 only. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Please make sure you have selected "Static Cells" in content option of Table View

[image: TableView]

Comment: As I mentioned in the post (and double-checked now) the table view's content IS set to static cells.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a UITableViewController that has a **table view** with static cells

Are you sure that your static table cells are within a UITableViewController and not within a UITableView embedded within a UIViewController? Storyboard will let you add table cells to a table view embedded within a standard view controller, but this wont work at runtime. Depending upon the version of ios you may or may not get an error. If the answer is yes, then you need to add the static table cells directly to the UI**Table**View**Controler**.

Comment: yes, the cells and sections are inside a table view that is inside of my table view controller. I did as you said but the cells disappeared as well!

Comment: I added the Scene hierarchy to the post.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. If you have a custom TableViewController but the TableViewCell Style is not set to custom this happens.
 I got around by changing the UITableViewController from my custom controller to the generic one. My guess is that if the controller is custom, then we are saying that we will supply the data programmatically so the storyboard data is not presented. There must be away to get around it, but I am too new to iOS to investigate. Besides, for prototyping generic UITableViewController works well enough.
So:
Go to the "Main Table View Controller"
Select the identity inspector.
Change the class from your custom class to UITableViewController

Or use your custom controller but change  TableViewCell.Style to Custom in the Attributes Inspector

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `dataSource` and the `delegate` for the `UITableViewController` to `self` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same problem these days. As mentioned by Aryan, I have to add constraints to Labels in the master view of `UISplitViewController`. Otherwise the content is not "`disappear`" but at the so left of the tableview cell that it is off the screen bounds. Set the trailing margin to superview works for me.

Answer (score -3):

Creating prototypes in Storyboard is all fine and dandy, but you still need to inform the tableView property of the cells at runtime.

To do this, you need to name each cell with a reuseIdentifier:

[image]

Then you name each reuse identifier explicitly in your code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Your problem resides in the fact that you didn't implement the dataSource, which does exactly as it's titled: supplies the data.

Good luck

Comment: there are 2 ways for populating a table view, one is dynamically creating cells at run time with the data that comes from say a database or web request, and 2 is statically using the xCode story board and designing the cells there.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I didn't notice we're using the worst addition in Xcode ever made. You still need to provide the dataSource. I'll make an edit outlining what needs to be done.

Comment: No, you don't need to provide a data source. The "data", the text in the cells, is provided from the storyboard.

Comment: that's the whole point of NOT using the dynamic way! If I STILL NEED TO PROVIDE THE DATASOURCE, what's the point of doing it the static way?!

Comment: I'm not sure what the point is of ever using a storyboard period, and yet, here we are.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time, 1- for table views that have only one set of data and will not change through the life time of an application, it is logical to use the static way. And as for the update to your answer, since the cells in static tables are not going to be reused I don't see why setting the reuse identifier would help. However I set it and still no content appears...

Comment: Reuse identifiers are only needed for cells that will be reused dynamically. By definition, static cells aren't reused, so identifiers are unnecessary.